Nilpotent subalgebras of $M_n(K)$
Let $A$ be a nilpotent subalgebra of $M_n(K)$ where $K$ is a field. Is it true that the index of $A$ is $\le n$?
I know that if $A$ has a matrix with nilpotency index $n$ then it is true, since, its Jordan form will be $1$'s below the main diagonal. We can change the basis so that the matrix will be in its Jordan form, and all the other matrices are in this basis.
Multiplying by this matrix in the left will "make the matrix go down by $1$" and in the right will "make the matrix go down by $1$". Then, if there is a non zero upper matrix in this algebra then, we can multiply with the Jordan matrix in both sides enough times in order to make it triangular with not all the entries in the main diagonal $0$, which will make a non nilpotent matrix in $A$, contradiction, since $A$ is nilpotent. In this case, every matrix is lower triangular, and we can conclude that the product of $n$ matrix is always $0$.
But I can't do this without this matrix, and I don't know if this result is true.

No,  a nilpotent algebra is a non unital algebra is an algebra $A$ in which there exist $m$ integer such that the product of $m$ elements in $A$ is $0$.  The index of this algebra is the smallest one.  I'm asking if a nilpotent algebra of $M_n(K)$ must have the index $\le n$.

Engel's theorem seems to imply this.
